# Gulp.js can't compile angular.js project due to excessive js errors?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gulp

I am trying to move from Grunt to Gulp.  This project has run fine under Grunt, so I must be doing something wrong in Gulp.

All the other tasks work except scripts.  I have tired now adding and commenting out sections.

I keep getting an error relating to an unexpected token.  Using mg-min:

```
stream.js:94
  throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
        ^
Error: Line 2: Unexpected token :
at throwError (/Users/stevelombardi/Documents/dsg/node_modules/gulp-ngmin/node_modules/ngmin/node_modules/esprima/esprima.js:1156:21)
```

With ng-min commented out and using Uglify (default):

```
Error caught from uglify: Unexpected token: punc (:) in /Users/stevelombardi/Documents/dsg/dist/scripts/main.min.js. Returning unminifed code
[gulp] gulp-notify: [Gulp notification] Scripts task complete
[gulp] Finished 'scripts' after 2.97 s
```

I'm stumped.  Here's the task:

```
// Scripts
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
return gulp.src([
    "bower_components/jquery/jquery.js",
    "bower_components/angular/angular.js",
    "bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "bower_components/modernizr/modernizr.js",
    "bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js",
    "bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js",
    "bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js",
    "bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js",
    "bower_components/jquery.easy-pie-chart/dist/angular.easypiechart.js",
    "bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js",
    "bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js",
    "bower_components/kapusta-jquery.sparkline/dist/jquery.sparkline.js",
    "bower_components/leaflet-dist/leaflet.js",
    "bower_components/angular-leaflet/dist/angular-leaflet-directive.js",
    "bower_components/ngprogress/build/ngProgress.js",
    "bower_components/angular-bootstrap-toggle-switch/angular-toggle-switch.js",
    "bower_components/flot/jquery.flot.js",
    "bower_components/flot/jquery.flot.resize.js",
    "bower_components/flot.tooltip/js/jquery.flot.tooltip.js",
    "bower_components/angular-flot/angular-flot.js",
    'src/scripts/**/*.js',
])
    .pipe(jshint('.jshintrc'))
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))

// .pipe(ngmin({
//     dynamic: false
// }))
// .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))

.pipe(concat('main.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
.pipe(rename({
    suffix: '.min'
}))
.pipe(uglify())
.pipe(gulp.dest('dist/scripts'))
    .pipe(notify({
        message: 'Scripts task complete'
    }));
});
```

Comment: do you have some try catch in your code ?

Comment: What version of _ngmin_ are you using?

Comment: Unrelated note: you are including 2 distribution files from the angular-ui-bootstrap: "bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap.min.js" and "bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" which is not needed, only one is required. Check for more: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#installation

Answer (score 0):

I think it's safe to say that the output from the two plugins together can be taken to indicate that you have a syntax error on line two of what is being passed to the ngmin or uglify.

The two plugins are just reacting a bit differently from each other.  One is helpfully telling you the line number, and the other is helpfully tell you the file name.

Since you've already renamed the file, it seems like they're talking about a file that is already minified, when in fact it's just that you renamed its in-memory representation prematurely.

For starters, I'd recommend not renaming the file until you have minified it because your error is confusing.  At that point, you'll probably see that the error appears in the file that is saved to dist/scripts/main.js (on line two of that file you apparently have an errant colon).